# При уменьшении масштаба возникают зазоры между контентом и border

Tags: html, css, border

Вопрос. Нормально ли то, что при уменьшении масштаба браузера у меня появляется зазор между контентом и бордером в кнопке **GO AHEAD**? Использую `background-clip: padding-box`, чтобы сделать полу-прозрачный `border`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 15px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 58px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(img/header.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Header Button */

.header-button {
  margin-top: 135px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-link {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="header-button">
      <a class="header-link" href="#">
                            Go Ahead
                        </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почему не обойтись малой кровью и сделать просто блок `:before` чуть большего размера и под основным блоком?

```css
body {
    background: url('https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/3/94/peizazh-priroda-pustynia-pesok-solntse.jpg')
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%), translateY(-50%);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;

    padding: 10px;
    
    font-size: 32px;
    
    color:      white;
    background: #1abc9c;
}

.btn:before {
    content: '';
    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    
    background: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class = 'center'>
  <div class = 'btn'>GO AHEAD</div></div>
</div>
```

Можно сделать через тень:

Для этого надо указать кнопке тень `box-shadow` по центру наружу без размытия и шириной в размер границы, т.е.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4);
```

Это самый короткий и наверное самый оптимальный вариант

```css
body {
    background: url('https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/3/94/peizazh-priroda-pustynia-pesok-solntse.jpg')
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%), translateY(-50%);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;

    padding: 10px;
    
    font-size: 32px;
    
    color:      white;
    background: #1abc9c;
    
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.4); 
}
```

```html
<div class = 'center'>
  <div class = 'btn'>GO AHEAD</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно. В силу моего незнания не стал использовать. Думал, что для подобных действий отведена иная функция

Comment: @m4gdark, сделать можно по разному - я бы рекомендовал вообще 2 способ ( я его добавил в ответ - посмотрите) - вы рисуете объект с тенью, НО ставите размытие тени `0px` - эффект тот же, но самый короткий код!!!